# Postgres dynamic insert in trigger function

Tags: postgresql, triggers, range

I am trying to create a trigger function that insert a new record to the audit tables dynamically.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION schema.table()
    RETURNS trigger
    LANGUAGE 'plpgsql'
    COST 100
    VOLATILE NOT LEAKPROOF
AS $BODY$
DECLARE
    _tablename text;
    BEGIN
        _tablename := 'user_audit';
        EXECUTE 'INSERT INTO audit.' || quote_ident(_tablename) || ' VALUES ($1.*)' USING OLD;
        RETURN NEW;
    END;
$BODY$;
```

Trigger function above works fine as it take everything in OLD and inserts it into the audit table as expected. However I have a tstzrange range column in my tables called timestampzt_range and what I need to do is set the value for it in audit table using LOWER(OLD.timestampzt_range), LOWER(NEW.timestampzt_range). How can I achieve this dynamically without using insert statement like below as I would like to use this trigger function on multiple tables.

```
INSERT INTO audit.user_audit
    (
        column_1,
        column_2,
        timestampzt_range 
    )
    VALUES
    (
        OLD.column_1,
        OLD.column_2,       
        tstzrange(LOWER(OLD.timestampzt_range), LOWER(NEW.timestampzt_range))
    );
```

I only need to use this on update and table name will be passed as a parameter to the trigger function if I can achieve dynamic statement. Only the audit columns are consistent across the entire database so it is important for me create insert using OLD or somehow dynamically extract everything from it but the timestampzt_range and then use tstzrange(LOWER(OLD.timestampzt_range), LOWER(NEW.timestampzt_range)) as value for the range column.

Answer (score 0):

First comment : you can use the `NEW` and `OLD` key words only in an `UPDATE` trigger. In an INSERT trigger, `OLD` doesn't exist. In a DELETE trigger, `NEW` doesn't exist. See the [manual](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/plpgsql-trigger.html#PLPGSQL-DML-TRIGGER).

Then you can replace in your trigger function

`'INSERT INTO audit.' || quote_ident(_tablename) || ' VALUES ($1.*)' USING OLD`

by

`'INSERT INTO audit.' || quote_ident(_tablename) || ' VALUES (OLD.column_1, OLD.column_2, tstzrange(LOWER(OLD.timestampzt_range), LOWER(NEW.timestampzt_range)))'`

so that to achieve your expected result.

Last but not least, your dynamic statement `EXECUTE 'INSERT INTO audit.' ...` is useless because `_tablename` is a static parameter declared inside the function.

Comment: @ Edouard H. I only need to use this on update and table name will be passed as a parameter to the trigger function if I can achieve dynamic statement. Only the audit columns are consistent across the entire database so it is important for me create insert using OLD or somehow dynamically extract everything from it but the timestampzt_range and then use tstzrange(LOWER(OLD.timestampzt_range), LOWER(NEW.timestampzt_range)) as value for the range column.

Comment: The trigger functions don't accept input parameters, see the [manual](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/plpgsql-trigger.html) : "A trigger function is created with the CREATE FUNCTION command, declaring it as a function with no arguments". Then `OLD.timestampzt_range` is not accepted in an `INSERT` trigger, because it just makes no sense. The question is : where does this information come from when you insert a new row ? And generally speaking, you should come back to your need instead of digging a solution which may not fit your need.